# Does EventEmitter simply map functions in an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, eventemitter

For example

```
var event = {
    message: function(message){console.log(message);}
}

//polling here
{
    if(response.type == "message")
    {
        event[response.type](response.message);
    }
}
```

should work similarly to

```
events.on("message", function(message){console.log(message);});

//polling here
{
    events.emit(response.type, response.message);
}
```

If not, how is it different to EventEmitter other than auxiliary functions like `.once`?

I'm using both at the same time for different reasons. EventEmitter is for event-driven functions while the `event` object is for keeping an organized set of functions to trigger from a single context (`event`).

EDIT:

Modified code to work with multiple functions/listeners.

```
var event = {
    message: []
}

event.message.push(function(message){console.log(message)});

//polling here
{
    if(response.type == "message")
    {
        for(var func in event[response.type])
        {
            event[response.type][func](response.message);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in broader perspective, it is indeed an object(EvenEmitter class) which exposes set of methods to register listener functions to an event and also to remove those listener functions, plus other various functions which mutates it's inner closed event object.

In addition to that all those core modules which fire events inherits from EventEmitter class thus gaining access to central event object.
Thus, yes it does map functions to an object.

Comment: I have updated the answer, but from my perspective it does.